# Access to the port 'COM5' is denied

Tags: c#, serial-port

I get the following error message `Access to the port 'COM5' is denied.` when running the method below from my form. I have tried entering the right baud rate of 9600 from the port setting of my device manager. I have also tried accessing the devices through Portmon but there is a bug that prevents me from being connected. Any alternative to solve this problem?

```
      //Fields
    List<string> myReceivedLines = new List<string>();

    //subscriber method for the port.DataReceived Event
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        while (sp.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                myReceivedLines.Add(sp.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
    {

        string selectedportname = default(string);
        DA.GetData(1, ref selectedportname);
        int selectedbaudrate = default(int);
        DA.GetData(2, ref selectedbaudrate);
        bool connecttodevice = default(bool);
        DA.GetData(3, ref connecttodevice);

        port.DtrEnable = true;   //enables the Data Terminal Ready (DTR) signal during serial communication (Handshaking)
        port.Open();             //Open the port
        if (!(port.IsOpen == true)) port.Open();


        if (connecttodevice == true)
        {
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            DA.SetDataList(0, myReceivedLines);
        }
```

Comment: What type of device are you trying to access, make sure nothing else is trying to use the device.

Comment: If your program crashes, sometimes the port gets stuck open, and a reboot is required.

Comment: The port is already opened by another process.  Or yours, don't click that button twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the use of SerialPort in a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or implement [IDisposable](http://dave-black.blogspot.se/2011/03/how-do-you-properly-implement.html)

```
// Dispose() calls Dispose(true)
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

// The bulk of the clean-up code is implemented in Dispose(bool)
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        // free managed resources
        if (_serialPort != null)
        {
            _serialPort.Dispose();
            _serialPort = null;
        }
    }
    // free native resources if there are any.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you describe the piece of code a bit more please? Where would it fit and what it does?

Comment: Thanks Johan, would you place the using statement before the method I posted to make sure that the comport is not used?

Comment: It looks like your port is a class variable so IDisposable is more suitable in your case.
call port.Dispose() in the dispose method see link for implementing IDisposable: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P

Comment: This is not helpful.  The DataReceived event handler can never run.

Comment: Did you get this working @Arthur Mamou-Mani 
I dont know this for sure but I think that if a breakpoint is placed in a using statement and then stopping the debugging when still within the using the Dispose is not executed and the port can be left in corrupted state

Comment: @JohanLarsson yes it works when closing and re-opening the form. I wished there was a better way though, like a disconnect button. Quite confused by what Hans Passant said about your reply. Can I use it?

Comment: It is hard to help without seeing more of your code, but you should try newing the port in the constructor and add a test before opening it:

if (!(comPort.IsOpen == true)) comPort.Open();
Wrapping the serialport in your own class is probably a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @JohanLarsson I added more to the code in the question. Doesn't the line `if (!(port.IsOpen == true)) port.Open();` prevents the port to open by creating a "chicken and egg" situation? Also where should I instanciate the following class: `SerialPort port = new SerialPort(selectedportname, selectedbaudrate, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);`

Comment: Can you help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589000/how-to-know-on-which-serial-port-external-device-is-connected-and-read-data-from/36589197#36589197

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with the listener of serial port, the main process get's stuck - since it is sync. process, got solved by creating a thread and a timer

```
                try
            {
                if (_serialConnection.IsOpen) _serialConnection.Close();
                _serialConnection.Open();
                Thread newThread = new Thread((obj) =>
                {
                    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    timer.Interval = 1000;
                    timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        _slave.Listen();
                    };
                    timer.Enabled = true;
                    timer.Start();
                    
                });
                newThread.IsBackground = true;
                newThread.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```